# Connecting two different users in the same website with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I want to put two different users playing the same game, if they input the same board size. I have to use XMLHttpRequest, here's my Join method to try to do this:

However at this point it only returns the gameId, how can I do this, I'm stuck.

```
function join(size) {
    joinData = {
        'group': user.group,
        'nick': user.username,
        'password': user.password,
        'size': size
    };
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("JOIN");

    xhr.open("POST", url + '/join', false);

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(joinData));

    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log("JOIN OK");
        
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: One would usually use a `websocket` for this type of situation. It allows bi-directional communication between your users and the the server.  `"I have to use XMLHttpRequest"`  - why?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.